# Jenkins Jacoco Code Covarage show trend as percentage

Tags: jenkins, code-coverage, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I have configured jacoco plugin to visualise trend to show number of lines covered. Is it possible to show this trend chart as percentage.